# I need my page to redirect after somebody cancels or effects data entry

Tags: c#-4.0

I need my page to redirect after somebody cancels or effects data entry. I have this but it seems not to be working. What am I missing?

```
<script runat="server">
protected void DetailsView_ItemInsert(object senderPage, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs evt)
{
    if (evt.AffectedRows == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/Home/"); //Confirm page
    }
}
protected void DetailsView_ItemsCancel(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs evt)
{
    if (evt.CommandName == "Cancel")
    {
        Response.Redirect("List.aspx"); //Cancel page
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the events are actually called? Also, in the cancel, it's already a cancel event I don't think you need to check the CommandName.